# Events and Buttons

Tags: c#, events, button

I want to get the text of the button whenever I click on it.

The algorithm that I  made is where i have a function that is a loop that creates a number of buttons and assigns numbers:

```
    void ListAllPage()
    {
        if (pageMax < 50)
        {
            //if page max less than 50
            for (int i = 0; i < pageMax; i++)
            {
                Button newBtn = new Button();
                newBtn.Text = i.ToString();
                newBtn.Width = 50;

                newBtn.Click += page_Clicked;

                pageCell.Controls.Add(newBtn);
            }
        }
}
```

Now buttons will appear on the screen, their events will be triggered and the function page_Click; will be executed:

```
 public void page_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

  //inside this function I want to obtain the button number that was clicked by the user. How do I do that?
    }
```

Take note, I must all the functions that I described here,...

My thinking is to feed all the buttons that i created inside the loop to a dictionary..
Dictionary.. it will take variables like this btndic.Add(Button b=new Button,b.text);

But the issue is how to retrieve the buttons,,,

if there is a better way, i would like to hear about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using the Click Event -> Use the Command Event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.oncommand.aspx then you can distinguish which button has been clicked

Answer (score 2):

You just need to cast the `sender` object to a `Button`, or more generally, a `Control`:

```
public void page_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Control c = sender as Control;
     MessageBox.Show("Clicked on " + c.Text);
}
```

Also, it might be more appropriate to use the `Tag` property to store your custom information (number). In that case, `Text` property can be anything you like.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
public void page_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   Button btn=(Button)sender;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your `ListAllPage` method assign `Tag` to each button:

```
newBtn.Tag = i;
```

In your handler you can obtain button instance from `sender`:

```
var clickedButton = (Button)sender;
int pageIndex = (int)clickedButton.Tag;
```

Comment: `tag` has no namespace. It is property of `Control`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx